# Max and Min of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f(x,y)=x(y \log y-y)-y \log x$. Find $\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(\smash{\displaystyle\min_{\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1} f(x,y)})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(\smash{\displaystyle\min_{\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1} f(x,y)}) \leq \smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}f(x,\frac{1}{2})=\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(-\frac{x\log 2+x+\log x}{2})$$

Since $-\frac{x\log 2+x+\log x}{2}$ is a decreasing function of $x$, we have

$$\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(-\frac{x\log 2+x+\log x}{2})=-\frac{\frac{1}{2}\log 2+\frac{1}{2}+\log \frac{1}{2}}{2}=\frac{\log 2-1}{4}$$

with equality when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. We claim that equality holds throughout and thus
$$\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(\smash{\displaystyle\min_{\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1} f(x,y)})=\frac{\log 2-1}{4}$$
It now suffices to show that 
$$\smash{\displaystyle\min_{\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1} f(\frac{1}{2},y)}=f(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$$

We have

$$f(\frac{1}{2}, y)=\frac{1}{2}y\log y-\frac{1}{2}y+y\log 2$$

$$\frac{d f(\frac{1}{2}, y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}\log y+\log 2>\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{1}{2}+\log 2=\frac{1}{2}\log 2>0$$

Therefore $f(\frac{1}{2}, y)$ is a non-decreasing function of $y$, and we are done.

Comment: Are you claiming that $f(x,y)\le f(x,{1\over2})$ in the first line? I don't think that's true at $x=.5$, by the plot.

Comment: @BradyTrainor I am not claiming that $f(x, y) \leq f(x, \frac{1}{2})$. I use the fact that $$\smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}(\smash{\displaystyle\min_{\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1} f(x,y)}) \leq \smash{\displaystyle\max_{\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2}}f(x,\frac{1}{2})$$ Let $min(f(x, y))=f(x, g(x))$, then $max(min(f(x, y)))=max(f(x, g(x))) \leq max(f(x, \frac{1}{2}))$.

Comment: @BradyTrainor see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have a feeling I'm missing some technique, is there another method I seem unaware of? /EDIT (By the way, from the graph, I'd guess it is at (x,y)=(.5,.5))

First, find the function of $x$, 
$$m(x)=\min_{y\in[.5,1]}f(x,y).$$
Fix $x$ and find $m(x)$ by any means necessary. We could use calculus to find the critical points, but the algebra looks a little tedious. Let's use a graphical program to get a clue:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28x%28ylogy%E2%88%92y%29%E2%88%92ylogx%2C+.5%3Cx%3C2%2C+.5%3Cy%3C1%29

From the linked plot, if we move in the $y$-direction, at $x=.5$, it is an increasing function, while at $x=2$, it is a decreasing function. Let's just check for critical points after all. We set

$$f_y(x,y)=x\log y-\log x=0,$$

so for any $x$, critical points along $y$ occur at they $y$ value $y=x^{1\over x}$. To find the minimum (at fixed $x$), we compare $f(x,x^{1\over x})$, $f(x,.5)$ and $f(x,1)$.

[image]

Comment: I get for $f(x,x^{\frac{1}{x}})=x^{\frac{1}{x}}(xln(x^{\frac{1}{x}})-lnx-x)$
$f(x,\frac{1}{2})=(-\frac{ln(2)}{2}-\frac{1}{2})x-\frac{ln(x)}{2}$ and $f(x,1)=-ln(x)-x$.

How do I compare the three ?

Comment: at least for y=.5, y=1, you could just set them equal and use IVT elsewhere

Comment: to make sure we are approaching this correctly, I'd want to know the name of textbook or class. or I guess we could google general methods for max min problems to make sure there isn't a shortcut... Unfortunately, I really have to get to other things, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $\frac12\le x\le 2,$ the function $g_x(y)=f(x,y)$ will be a differentiable function in the variable $y$ on the positive reals. Then $g_x(y)$ can only achieve its minimum in the closed interval $\left[\frac12,2\right]$ at the boundary, or at a critical point in its interior.

Now, for $y>0$ we have $$g_x'(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[f(x,y)\right]=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[y\log y\right]-x-\log x=x\log y-\log x=\log\frac{y^x}x,$$ which has its sole zero when $y^x=x$. Since $$g''_x(y)=\frac xy$$ is positive for all $y>0,$ then $g_x$ has a **global** minimum when $y^x=x$ and $y>0,$ namely $$\begin{align}g_x(x^{1/x}) &= x\left(x^{1/x}\log(x^{1/x})-x^{1/x}\right)-x^{1/x}\log x\\ &= x\left(x^{1/x}\frac1x\log x-x^{1/x}\right)-x^{1/x}\log x\\ &= -x^{1+\frac1x}.\end{align}$$ You should verify that $x\mapsto-x^{1+\frac1x},$ $x\mapsto g_x(1/2),$ and $x\mapsto g_x(2)$ are decreasing functions on $[\frac12,2],$ so each will be maximized on that interval when $x=\frac12.$ Hence, $$\max_{\frac12\le x\le2}\min_{\frac12\le y\le2}g_x(y)=\min_{\frac12\le y\le2}g_{1/2}(y).$$ Note in particular that for $x=\frac12$, we have $x^{1/x}=\frac14,$ which is *not* in the interior of the closed interval. That is, $g_{1/2}(y)$ doesn't have a critical point in the interior of closed interval, so is minimized on the boundary, meaning $$\min_{\frac12\le y\le2}g_{1/2}(y)=\min\{g_{1/2}(1/2),g_{1/2}(2)\}=\min\{f(1/2,1/2),f(1/2,2)\}.$$ I'll let you take it from there.